# "detail": "Метод \"GET\" не разрешен." в permissions

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Я написал свои permission_classes:

```
from rest_framework import permissions


class IsAdminOrReadOnly(permissions.BasePermission):
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        if request.method in permissions.SAFE_METHODS:
            return True
        return bool(request.user and request.user.is_staff)


class IsOwnerOrReadOnly(permissions.BasePermission):
    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        if request.methods in permissions.SAFE_METHODS:
            return True
        return obj.user == request.user
```

И использовал их во вьюшке:

```
class AnimalAPIView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Animal.objects.all()
    serializer_class = AnimalSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly]


class AnimalAPIUpdate(generics.UpdateAPIView):
    queryset = Animal.objects.all()
    serializer_class = AnimalSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsOwnerOrReadOnly]


class AnimalAPIDestroy(generics.DestroyAPIView):
    queryset = Animal.objects.all()
    serializer_class = AnimalSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAdminOrReadOnly]
```

Но выходит ошибка:

```
{
    "detail": "Метод \"GET\" не разрешен."
}
```

Затем я поменял на permission_classes = [AllowAny], но ничего не изменилось я не могу получить данные. В чём может быть причина?

urls:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    #path('api/v1/', include(router.urls))
    path('api/v1/auth', include('rest_framework.urls')),
    path('api/v1/animal/', AnimalAPIView.as_view()),
    path('api/v1/animal/<int:pk>', AnimalAPIUpdate.as_view()),
    path('api/v1/animaldestoy/<int:pk>', AnimalAPIDestroy.as_view())
]
```

Ну и сериализатор, если нужен:

```
class AnimalSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = serializers.HiddenField(default=serializers.CurrentUserDefault())

    class Meta:
        model = Animal
        fields = "__all__"
```

Answer (score 0):

Спустя 3 дня я нашёл ошибку, в общем классы вьюшки должны наследоваться немного от других классов:
class AnimalAPIUpdate(generics.UpdateAPIView)-> AnimalAPIUpdate(generics.RetrieveUpdateAPIView)

class AnimalAPIDestroy(generics.DestroyAPIView)->
class AnimalAPIDestroy(generics.RetrieveDestroyAPIView)